# Global variables and multiprocessing pools

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables, python-multiprocessing

In the python multiprocessing library, do processes spawned via `Pool` only have access to global variables bound at the time of `Pool` construction?
Why is this?

This appears to be the case, based on this experiment.
This code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

x = 0


class MyClass:

    def get_x(self, i):
        global x
        return x


def foo():

    global x

    p = Pool(5)

    for i in range(3):
        x = i
        c = MyClass()

        print(list(p.imap(c.get_x, range(10*i, 10*i+10))))


foo()
```

produces the output

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Whereas moving the `Pool` construction inside the loop, i.e.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

x = 0


class MyClass:

    def get_x(self, i):
        global x
        return x


def foo():

    global x

    for i in range(3):
        p = Pool(5)

        x = i
        c = MyClass()

        print(list(p.imap(c.get_x, range(10*i, 10*i+10))))


foo()
```

produces the output

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

(Note that my motivation for wanting to do this is that `x` is a large pandas `DataFrame` in my real application, that needs to be read, but not modified, by several processes.)

My two questions are:

1. Is it merely impossible to *rebind* `x` once the processes are created?
2. Or do the processes each make a *copy* of `x`, and modification is impossible?

Comment: They create *independent python processes* with independent memory. This is very important to understand.

Comment: Note, exactly how this works will depend on if you use `spawn` versus `fork`